# Use GPO to set the size of temporary internet files in IE 11

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, browser-cache, internet-explorer-11, temporary-internet-files

I'm looking to change the default settings of IE 11 for Temporary Internet Files:

[image: img]

I need to do this with a GPO on a Windows Server 2012 R2

I've tried to do that like this:

[image: img]

But I don't now why I can't change the value

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Built-in GPO give no options for controlling the cache size. However, there are custom Administrative Templates that add this capability.

Personally, I'd recommend the template offered by Petri.com as that is a reputable site: https://www.petri.com/controlling_ie_cache_size_via_gpo

Once you've added the Administrative Template you'll find the settings under *UserConfiguration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Cache*.

Comment: Thank you, man! You really helped me with this but I have a little problem: the link for grabbing the .ADM isn't working! Do you have a copy of that file maybe?

Comment: Good question. I saw you commented on the post. Perhaps sending them a Tweet wouldn't be a bad idea either. A brief Google search didn't turn anything else up. I'll spend more time on this in a few days.